# How to distribute a number into pre-defined set of numbers in PHP

Tags: php, c

I am new in PHP but got a consignment from college to write a script to do following :-

```
$num1=0.1;
$num10=0.2;
$num50=0.3;
$num100=0.4;
```

If user type number **22** then result will be `$num10+$num10+$num1+num1`

If user type number **62** then result will be `$num50+$num10+$num1+num1`

If user type number **3** then result will be `$num1+$num1+num1`

I am not getting how to program this in PHP or C. Please help me if you think it's possible.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This seems like a variant of the [change-making problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Change-making_problem).

Comment: Please don't spam language tags. Use only one tag which is relevant to your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Yes I is possible. For sure.
Use two maps, a for loop and modulo.

Let me know if you need help.

*Meanwhile: I coded the solution also.*

Comment: i cant see solution??

Answer (score 0):

Finally I got it working using Change making Problem using Greedy algorithm.

```
<form method="post" action="coin.php">
Enter numbers : <input type="text" name="amount"/><input type="submit" value="Click here to Distribute Numbers into available pricing units">
</form>
<?php

function makeChange($amount) {
    $c = array(100, 50, 10, 1);
    $sol = array();
    $sum = 0;
    $i = 0;
    $ele = $c['0'];
    while ($sum != $amount) {
        $sum = $sum + $ele;
        if ($sum > $amount) {
            $sum = $sum - $ele;
            $i++;
            $ele = $c[$i];
            continue;
        }
        $sol[] = $ele;
    }
    return $sol;
}
if(isset($_POST['amount']))
{
$amount = $_POST['amount'];
$sol = makeChange($amount);
foreach ($sol as $val) {
    echo "<b>$val</B><br/> ";
}
}

?>
```